# C# Sending image data to view having double slash that breaks image src

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, image

I work on sending images which are retrieved from the databse to the view.

I converted the `byte[]` image data to a string and send it to the view via `ViewBag`

The image src string contains `//` that escapes the rest of the string and it errors on the client-side.

How to solve this problem?

**Error:**

[image]
[image]

**Controller:**

```
string imgSrc = null;
string base64 = null;
if (viewModel.Image != null)
{
    base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(viewModel.Image);
    imgSrc = string.Format("data:image/png;base64,{0}", base64);
}
ViewBag.ImageSource  = imgSrc;
```

**View:**

```
@{
    var propertyId = Model.PropertyId;
    var imageSource = ViewBag.ImageSource;
}
<div id="example" class="k-content">

<div class="demo-section k-content wide">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="images">
            <div class="image">
                <img src="@imageSource"/>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="dropZoneElement">
            <div class="textWrapper">
                <p>Add Image</p>
                <p class="dropImageHereText">Drop image here to upload</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<input name="files" id="files" type="file" />

<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="template">
    <div class="image"></div>
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var template = kendo.template($("#template").html());

        var initialFiles = [];
        var image = @imageSource;

        $("#images").html(kendo.render(template, initialFiles));

        $("#images").append('<div class="image"><img src="' + image + '" /></div>');

        $("#files").kendoUpload({
            async: {
                saveUrl: "save?id=" + @propertyId,
                removeUrl: "remove",
                autoUpload: true
            },
            multiple: false,
            validation: {
                allowedExtensions: [".jpg", ".jpeg", ".png", ".bmp", ".gif"]
            },
            success: onSuccess,
            dropZone: ".dropZoneElement"
        });

        function onSuccess(e) {
            if (e.operation == "upload") {
                var file = e.files[0].rawFile;

                if (file) {
                    var reader = new FileReader();

                    reader.onloadend = function () {
                        $("#images").empty().append("<div class='image'><img src=" + this.result + " /></div>");
                    };

                    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                }
            }
            if (e.operation == "remove") {
                $("#images").empty();
            }
        }
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is causing the problem:

```
'<div class="image"><img src=' + @imageSource + ' /></div>'
```

and also this line:

```
var image = @imageSource;
```

should be:

```
var image = "@imageSource";
```

Change it to:

```
'<div class="image"><img src="' + image + '" /></div>'
// Add double quotes         ^-------------^
```

You are adding the string `image` without double quotes in image src, so it becomes something like:

```
<img src=some string />
```

but it should be like:

```
<img src="some string" />
```

And also change `@imageSource` to `image`

You can of course use single quotes to but need to scape them like:

```
'<div class="image"><img src=\'' + image + '\' /></div>'
```

**Solution 2**:

Just remove the line:

```
var image = @imageSource;
```

from your javascript and change the line:

```
$("#images").append('<div class="image"><img src="' + image + '" /></div>');
```

to:

```
$("#images").append('<div class="image"><img src="@imageSource" /></div>');
```

Comment: I add double quotes. Still having the problem. Also updated error in the question. I think the problem is from `//` in the src string.

Comment: and as in the answer change `@imageSource` to `image`

Comment: no there were 2 problems: 1 not wrapping in double quotes, 2, using C# Razor variable like a javascript variable: `var image = @imageSource;`
should be:

`var image = "@imageSource";`

Comment: and also change` <img src="' + @imageSource + '" />` to `<img src="' + image + '" />`

Comment: Yes, you're right `var image = "@imageSource";` is needed as well. Seems works fine now.

Comment: I also added a second solution to the bottom of my answer.

Comment: The second solution works as well and even better to save one line :)

Comment: @SalomonZhang glad it helped